# Преобразовать Строку System.in.next() в LocalDate

Tags: java, строки, localdate

Суть такова, пользователь вводит дату в любом из форматов dd.mm.yyyy, dd.mm.yy, dd/mm/yyyy, dd/mm/yy и на выходе эта строка преобразуется в LocalDate

Как получить из строки LocalDate я понимаю, но никак не получается сделать преобразование сразу для всех типов.

Comment: Пробовать через try все форматы. Перед этим можно заменить / на . чтобы сократить варианты.

Comment: Выкидывает ошибку

Comment: Раз выкидывает ошибку, значит неправильный код

Comment: все разобрался в чем проблема

Comment: День. Минуты. Год... Странный формат...

Comment: @Олексій Моренець День месяц год) просто торопился скорее написать поэтому с маленькой буквы

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, вы получаете на вход строку `String date`. Можно поступить так:

**1.** Проверьте строку: `date.contains('.')`. Это поможет поделить строки на разделяющиеся слэшем и разделяющиеся точкой.

**2.** В зависимости от шага 2 сделайте `String[] dateParts = date.split(".")` или `date.split("/")`.

**3.** Вы получили массив, состоящий из года, месяца и дня. Дальше вы можете сделать так:

```
LocalDate curDate = LocalDate.of(
Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2].length == 2 ? "20" + dateParts[2] : dateParts[2]), 
Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]),
Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]));
```

Проверка на длину строки года нужны, чтобы получить строку вида `2019`.

Вот и всё. Вы получили нужную дату.